# Where to have an SVN repository

Tags: svn, web-hosting

I would like to set up my own SVN repository on my hosting account but I have shared hosting and don't have the funds right now or a significant startup site to actually get a VPS. Is there shared hosting out there that enables you to do this? I may not be that knowledgeable on this so please inform me if I am wrong.  I am new to SVN and know that there are free SVN hosting out there like Codesion but I would like the ability to be able to post-commit after every commit.  I believe I am using the right terminology, but basically I want a production environment where I will have a subdomain for development and testing purposes that whenever an SVN commit is made to my SVN repository it will automatically update that to my development subdomain and export the files.  This way all changes that everyone makes can be seen in that subdomain.

I am currently the only one working on the website but I may be having some more friends work on it with me and I'd like the ability to use SVN this way.  Am I going about this the right way?  Is there a better solution to this regarding my resources?  What is the best practice to managing a working website like this that will constantly be updated and have new features.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com/) with [Subversion](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Subversion).

But in you case [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com) with [webhooks](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/Webhook_message_templates) or [Build](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/Build_Tool)|[FTP](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/breakoutdocs/wiki/FTP_Tool) tool may be acceptable also